# any msbuild file parsers available?

Tags: msbuild

I am looking for an MSbuild file parser. Currently I have written my own that is not complete... but I feel like I am reinventing the wheel building something that surely exists already.

Comment: the parser depends on what goal do you want to achive whith the parser. I have created two different: one for backup of all files in a solution and one that sould become a wizzard to create wix-files. what do you want to do with the parser?

Comment: I would like to analyze my msbuild files and visualize the targets in a homegrown "msbuild runner" application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info I have found here... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/b3db4d7c-b7d1-4958-9145-bfd34cc75320

In addition there is a small projects with some highlevel samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuildho

```
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Project testProj = new Project();
        testProj.Xml.AddTarget("BuildProjects");
        foreach (ProjectTargetElement pti in testProj.Xml.Targets.Where(pti => pti.Name == "BuildProjects"))
        {
            pti.AddTask("MSBuild");   
        }   
        testProj.Save(@"C:\testProj.proj");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft.Build.Construction.XXX in microsoft.build.dll (version 4.0+) is a "raw" parser of MSBuild files. It is powerful and complete and analogous to the XML DOM. It works on a single file, doing no evaluation. It's useful for example when you want to run a script over a tree of projects to edit them in some way, perhaps to add a common import statement.

Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.XXX works on evaluated projects -- ie., with all the properties evaluated, imported files pulled in and so forth. It's useful in a development environment - you can read off the files and properties in the project, add new files and so forth. Visual Studio uses it for this purpose.

Before 4.0, there was a completely different, much more limited, and less complete object model in microsoft.build.engine.dll. It still ships with 4.0 but cannot handle some 4.0 syntax. It is deprecated.

I designed and implemented these so I'd be interested in feedback if you have any.

Comment: I found these 2 urls, but they don't contain any sample code and I think [1] is not what you mean. Can you point me to samples? thank you! 1.[] ; X.Download Log Parser 2.2 from Official Microsoft Download Center ;; http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659  ;  2.[] ; X.Microsoft.Build.Construction Namespace () ;; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction(v=vs.121).aspx