# Add Files programmatically to VS Project for UnitTests

Tags: tfs, project, solution

I am creating Class Files programmatically for UnitTests with NUnit. 
I could already add them to TFS Source Control.
What I now need, is that I want to add them programmatically to the Project.

I have found several approaches, but I got none working... I don't want to edit the XMl-File manually.

Do you have some code snippets?

Comment: Are you generating unittests on the fly ? or do you just need a project file which contains all class files that reside in a directory (structure) because they used to be compiled differently ?

Answer (score 6):

The naïve solution would be to edit the XML file manually. However, you don't have to do this.

You can use the [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) object model to manipulate Visual Studio project files. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727499/11210) for more information on the differences between the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` and `Microsoft.Build.Construction` namespaces.

The following example opens `YourProject.csproj` and adds a new file called `YourFile.cs` as a `Compile` item type, then saves the project file back to disk.

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var project = new Project(@"YourProject.csproj");
            project.AddItem("Compile", "YourFile.cs");
            project.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only for .net 4.0 and above ?

Comment: I was about to edit the XML manually. That would've been a nightmare. This is what I'm looking for.